# Postgres. Conditional stored data uniqueness

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have an Application type in my app.

```
public class Application {
   private String id;
   private String creator;
   private boolean active;
}
```

`active` field marks is current application actual for certain user. Every user is able to have only one `application` in active(`active == true`) state and any number of inactive applications(`active == false`).

Is it possible to deny storing second application record with same `creator` value and `active == true`, but let save any number of applications with same `creator` value and `active == false` on DB level(Postgres)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) can solve this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX active_application_per_user ON application (creator) WHERE active;
```